# How can I perform a multi touch swipe with Espresso?

Tags: testing, android-espresso, gui-testing, ui-testing

How can I perform a multi touch swipe with Espresso? e.g. a two finger swipe to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  @Daniel suggested, I created a custom version of MotionEvents, because when using multiple fingers you have to inject ACTION_POINTER_DOWN/UP instead of ACTION_DOWN/UP.
And I created a twoFinger version of LinearSwipe, like this:

```
private static Swiper.Status sendLinearSwipe(UiController uiController,
                                             float[] startCoordinates,
                                             float[] startCoordinatesSecondFinger,
                                             float[] endCoordinates,
                                             float[]endCoordinatesSecondFinger,
                                             float[] precision,
                                             float[] precisionSecond,
                                             int duration) {
    checkNotNull(uiController);
    checkNotNull(startCoordinates);
    checkNotNull(startCoordinatesSecondFinger);
    checkNotNull(endCoordinates);
    checkNotNull(endCoordinatesSecondFinger);
    checkNotNull(precision);
    checkNotNull(precisionSecond);

    float[][] steps = interpolate(startCoordinates, endCoordinates, SWIPE_EVENT_COUNT);
    float[][] stepsSecondFinger = interpolate(startCoordinatesSecondFinger, endCoordinatesSecondFinger, SWIPE_EVENT_COUNT);
    final int delayBetweenMovements = duration / steps.length;
    final int delayBetweenMovementsSecondFinger = duration / stepsSecondFinger.length;

    int maxLength=Math.min(steps.length, stepsSecondFinger.length);

    MotionEvent downEvent;
    downEvent = MotionEvents.sendDown(uiController, steps[0], precision,true).down;
    MotionEvent downEventSecondFinger;
    downEventSecondFinger = MotionEvents.sendDown(uiController,stepsSecondFinger[0], precisionSecond,false).down;

    try {
        for (int i = 1; i < maxLength; i++) {

            if (sendMovement(uiController, steps[i], downEvent)) return Status.FAILURE;
            if (sendMovement(uiController, stepsSecondFinger[i], downEventSecondFinger)) return Status.FAILURE;


            long desiredTime = downEvent.getDownTime() + delayBetweenMovements * i;
            long desiredTimeSecondFinger = downEventSecondFinger.getDownTime() + delayBetweenMovementsSecondFinger * i;

            long timeUntilDesired = desiredTime - SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long timeUntilDesiredSecondFinger = desiredTimeSecondFinger - SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            loopMainThread(uiController, timeUntilDesired);
            loopMainThread(uiController, timeUntilDesiredSecondFinger);

        }

        if (!MotionEvents.sendUp(uiController, downEventSecondFinger, endCoordinatesSecondFinger,false)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Injection of up event as part of the swipe failed. Sending cancel event.");
            MotionEvents.sendCancel(uiController, downEventSecondFinger);
            return Swiper.Status.FAILURE;
        }
    } finally {
        downEvent.recycle();
        downEventSecondFinger.recycle();
    }
    return Swiper.Status.SUCCESS;
}

private static void loopMainThread(UiController uiController, long timeUntilDesired) {
    if (timeUntilDesired > 10) {
        uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(timeUntilDesired);
    }
}

private static boolean sendMovement(UiController uiController, float[] step, MotionEvent downEvent) {
    if (!MotionEvents.sendMovement(uiController, downEvent, step)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Injection of move event as part of the swipe failed. Sending cancel event.");
        MotionEvents.sendCancel(uiController, downEvent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now it works perfectly! Thanks @Daniel

Comment: can you also include the interpolate method in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Espresso doesn't provide that functionality, but you could do it yourself by

- injecting two down events
- injecting several pairs of motion events, one for each finger
- injecting two up events

Espresso has some utilities to make it easier. In particular, the `MotionEvents` class has some helper methods for creating and injecting those low-level events.

You may want to reference the [`sendLinearSwipe`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/Swipe.java#78) code which contains most of the logic for single touch swipes.

If you write this as a `ViewAction`, it will fit cleanly into the Espresso framework (e.g., you can easily have it wait for idling resources).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work now. However it fails when I inject two up events. But if I only inject one up event it works fine :)